# transform data by conditional addition

Tags: python, pandas

I need help transforming the data as follows:

From a dataset in this version (df1)

```
   ID  apples  oranges  pears  apples_pears  oranges_pears
0   1       1        0      0             1              0
1   2       0        1      0             1              0
2   3       0        1      1             0              1
```

to a data set like the following (df2):

```
   ID  apples  oranges  pears
0   1       2        0      1
1   2       1        1      1
2   3       0        2      2
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is get the total values of apples, from all the columns in which the word "apple" appears in the column name. E.g. in the df1 there are 2 column names in which the word "apple" appears. If you sum up all the apples from the first row, there would be a total of 2. I want a single column for apples in the new dataset (df2). Note that a 1 for appleas_pears is a 1 for EACH apples and pears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is split `DataFrame` to new 2 - first change columns names by all values before `_` and for second filter columns with `_` by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and change columns by value after `_`, last join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and sum per columns:

```
df1 = df.set_index('ID')
df2 = df1.filter(like='_')

df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_').str[0]
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.split('_').str[1]

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).sum(level=0, axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
   ID  apples  oranges  pears
0   1       2        0      1
1   2       1        1      1
2   3       0        2      2
```